# inverse permutation in prolog

Tags: prolog, permutation

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

[An inverse permutation is a permutation in which each number and the number of the place which it occupies are exchanged. For example [3,8,5,10,9,4,6,1,7,2] -> [8,10,1,6,3,7,9,2,5,4]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InversePermutation.html)

```
inv_perm3(X,[F],length(X)):-
    length([F]) == 1,
    !,
    nth0(F,X,length(X)).
inv_perm3(X,[F|M],N):-
    nth0(F,X,N),            %nth0(?Index, List, Elem)
    F is F+1,
    N1 is N+1,
    inv_perm3(X,M,N1).

inv_perm(A,B):-
    inv_perm3(A,B,1).
```

I get false in every input, I test it like this: inv_perm( [2,3,1], X ).

Comment: You have some basic misunderstanding of how Prolog works. Predicates, as they are called rather than "functions*, do not "return" values. They either just succeed or fail (or do not terminate). So `length([F]) == 1` will always fail since you are asking Prolog whether the term `length([F])` is identical to `1` which is not possible. Prolog doesn't compute the length of `[F]` in this context. In Prolog, `length/2` is a predicate which succeeds if the second argument is the length of the list given by the first argument.

Comment: `F is F + 1` will always fail since `F` and `F+1` can never have the same value at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's way simpler... a hint

```
?- X=[3,8,5,10,9,4,6,1,7,2],same_length(Y,X),nth1(I,X,V),nth1(V,Y,I).
X = [3, 8, 5, 10, 9, 4, 6, 1, 7|...],
Y = [_358, _364, 1, _376, _382, _388, _394, _400, _406|...],
I = 1,
V = 3 ;
X = [3, 8, 5, 10, 9, 4, 6, 1, 7|...],
Y = [_358, _364, _370, _376, _382, _388, _394, 2, _406|...],
I = 2,
V = 8 ;
...
```

while I've shown only 1 element of both lists, you should use forall/2 to check all elements, or findall/3 to relate both lists. Findall would allow to generate the inverse, while forall just would check for correctness